# Translation Golf XLIX - An Accurate Shot

Tags: traducción, translation-golf, inglés

> **La edición del translation golf ha terminado. Si bien la respuesta de Walen es la más corta entregada, a mi parecer hace falta por lo menos un sujeto para una redacción adecuada. Por tanto, la respuesta de Chococroc con 23 caracteres es la ganadora del juego**

Welcome to a new edition of the game! If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

---

In this edition, I choose the 2nd amendment to the US Constitution. The 'original' version [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution#Text):

> A well regulated Militia, being necessary to the security of a free State, the right of the people to keep and bear Arms, shall not be infringed.
>
> <sub>(115 characters.)</sub>

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

As an initial point, the Wikipedia translation, (with 2 adjust from me) says:

> Para la seguridad de un Estado libre, siendo necesaria una Milicia bien organizada, el derecho del pueblo a poseer y portar Armas, no será infringido
>
>   <sub>(122 characters.)</sub>

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters? Join us in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Comment: I wonder why this was downvoted?  Is it because this text maybe doesn't lend itself to the game as well as some do?

Comment: lo has puesto difícil

Comment: Propuesta de traducción (léase [cantando](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAYfXyC5QMQ)): _No me toques las armas que me conozco..._

Comment: @aparente001, I would guess that it's been downvoted because the meaning of the English is strongly debated. If there's disagreement over what the original text's meaning and concepts are, how can people know whether their translations preserve them?

Comment: @PeterTaylor The traditional solution to this is to make the translation ambiguous in an equivalent way.

Comment: And looking at some of the more recent answers, I think that the question urgently needs an enumeration of the points which must be covered, as in e.g. [this earlier round](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26133/278).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**23 caracteres**

> Sólo con armas pueblo libre.

Intento resumir en la frase todo el contenido de la versión original.

Comment: Felicidades, has ganado el juego. Cuentas con 48 horas para presentar un nuevo Translation Golf si lo deseas. Transcurrido el tiempo, cualquiera podrá presentar una traducción para la siguiente edición del juego.

Comment: @VeAqui, gracias, intentaré poner una lo antes posible, :D.

Answer (score 7):

#### <strike>89 78 67 56 45 34 23</strike> 12

> Inerme o libre.

Comment: Google no me ayudó mucho con tuáutem (recurso extraordinario...). Me apareció habitualmente como *el* tuáutem. Si me ayudas con un ejemplo, bienvenido

Comment: Wow, tuáutem. La primera vez que lo veo en mi vida. GRANDIOSO

Comment: La versión de 23 caracteres no me parece una interpretación muy defensible. Cómo mucho creo que se puede justificar la interpretación de que "*Pueblo sin armas perderá la libertad*" (en algún momento futuro sin especificar). Y eso requiere que "*security of a free state*" signifique la seguridad de que el estado siga libre, y no la seguridad contra enemigos externos (contrastado el uso de la milicia en un estado libre con un ejército mercenario de un estado menos libre).

Comment: Repito lo que he dicho antes. Ese argumento sirve para justificar que un pueblo sin armas *puede perder* su libertad, *in extremis* que seguramente la *perderá*, pero no equivale a *haberla perdido ya* a no ser que se entre en razonamiento circular (de que la libertad que vale es la libertad de armarse) o anárquico (que la existencia del gobierno quita la libertad).

Comment: Como lema de la NRA sería adecuado... e incluso creo que es la ibterpretación que más de uno le da a la 2da enmienda. A mi parecer falta uno o 2 sujetos en la frase. ¿Quién ha de armarse? ¿La libertad de quién se busca?

Comment: La respuesta de 12 caracteres no me parece válida para el juego, bien se puede cambiar y los demás participantes considerar opciones de 23 o menos caracteres.

Answer (score 7):

#### <s>78 65 38</s> 29 caracteres

> No hay país libre y seguro sin [armas](https://dle.rae.es/?id=3a3iLLv)<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> Acepción 8: f. pl. Milicia o profesión militar. Se usa pues en doble sentido, significando que el pueblo debe tener tanto armas como milicia.

Comment: ¿Por la seguridad de quién?

Comment: @VeAqui la del propio pueblo, he hecho un pequeño cambio para reflejarlo.

Answer (score 6):

#### <s>97</s> 29 caracteres

> Un país armado protege su libertad

Answer (score 6):

#### 57 caracteres

> Todos podrán alistarse pues sin armas faltará seguridad o libertad.

Aclaraciones:

- Cojo de la respuesta de Charlie la palabra *armas* por *milicia*.
- Tomo por guía interpretiva los [estudios históricos del lingüista Neal Goldfarb](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=43559)

Comment: Te quedo debiendo la revisión del escrito de Goldfarb (Estos 115 caracteres en más de 200 años se han interpretado en idioma original de muchas formas y creeme que darle un determinado sentido lo más corto posible en otro idioma).

Answer (score 4):

**49 caracteres**

> Garantizad armas al Pueblo ya que defiende la Patria

Es mi primera participación en el Golf, no sé si habré infringido alguna norma o me habré pasado resumiendo.

- Garantizar - Dar garantía - Afianzar lo estipulado - Mantener el derecho
- Defender - Amparar, librar [misma raíz que libre]
- Defender - Proteger - Asegurar [misma raíz que seguridad] [Inspirado por la defensa de @walen]

La frase de @Charlie, "No me toques las armas que me conozco", no sé porqué me ha recordado lo de "Armas pa'l Pueblo" y he intentado ampliarlo para que cumpla la normativa y refleje mejor el texto original.

Comment: Para ser tu primer juego, es bastante buena la propuesta que haces. El objetivo es recortar al máximo... sin perder la coherencia gramatical del español ni la idea original del texto a traducir (según el OP)

Answer (score 3):

**27 caracteres**

> El pueblo usará armas en defensa.

*Usará* en sentido permisivo.

Comment: Más que interesante la respuesta... pero ¿En defensa de qué usará armas el pueblo?

Answer (score 3):

#### 46 caracteres

> Para ser libre y seguro, el pueblo debe poder tener armas

Answer (score 2):

**35 caracteres**

> Milicia y libertad de armas: estado libre.